# Virtualenv "workon" command online working in one terminal tab.

Tags: django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm working on a django project.

I hav virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper setup.  When I invoke

```
workon myprojectname
```

I cannot invoke it again in another terminal tab or window.  Any ideas why?
Does it have anything to do with postactivate hooks? I wouldn't think so.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: that should not be the case. what is the error message?

Comment: Doesn't do anythin just jumps down to a new commandline.  After a restart it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 7):

Have you added the virtualenvwrapper commands to your startup shell file?

For Example, if you're using Terminal on Mac, add the following lines to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file

Comment: I've added those lines to the ~/.bashrc file on a linux system.  I always get the error "PROJECT_HOME" does not exists.